# show that $ d(a, f(a)) \leq d(x, f(x)) \leq d(b, f(b)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a compact metric space and $g:(E, d) \rightarrow(\mathbb{R},|.|), x \mapsto d(x, f(x))$, such that  $f:(E, d) \rightarrow(E, d)$ verify: $d(f(x), f(y))<d(x, y) \text { if } x \neq y$  
show that there exists $a,b\in E$ $$ d(a, f(a)) \leq d(x, f(x)) \leq d(b, f(b)),\forall x \in E$$ 
my attempt: 
since E is compact then $a\leq x \leq b$ and since g is continuous  so $f(E)$ is compact
so $f(a)\leq f(x) \leq f(b)$ Hence $d(a, f(a)) \leq d(x, f(x)) \leq d(b, f(b))$

Comment: You are using the function $f$ in the definition of $f$ so the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis sorry wait a minute

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis this is the third question in the problem that's why i missed that

Comment: Actually, $g$ is also continuous, since the metric $d:E\times E\to \mathbb{R}_+$ is always continuous.

Comment: @Z.Zhu yes it's lipschitz function

Comment: $f(a)\leq f(x)\leq f(b)$ doesn’t make sense, since $f(t)\in E,$ and there is no order on $E.$ You probably mean $g(a)\leq g(x)\leq g(b).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes

Comment: Then **edit** your question. @vemapo